# How do I add a blur effect at the right edge horizontal ListView to show that there is more content

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I would like a way for the user to see that they can scroll horizontally on my horizontal ListView

Thanks in advance

Edit:

Here is my code @wcyankees424

```
Container(
  height: 50,
  child: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: cheat.buttons.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ButtonListItem(cheat.buttons[index]);
          }
      ),
      Positioned(
        top: 0,
        right: 0,
        width: 50,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        child: ClipRRect(
          child: BackdropFilter(
            filter: ImageFilter.blur(
                sigmaX: 0,
                sigmaY: 99
            ),
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      )
    ],
  )
),
```

And here is a picture of how it looks now: 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this the effect you wanted? Try this out let me know what you think.

```
Positioned(
            top: 0,
            right: 0,
            width: 50,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            child: ClipRRect(
              child: BackdropFilter(
                filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 2.5, sigmaY: 2.5), //this determines the blur in the x and y directions best to keep to relitivly low numbers
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    gradient: LinearGradient(
                      colors: [
                        Colors.black.withOpacity(0),
                        Colors.black.withOpacity(
                            0.3), //This controls the darkness of the bar
                      ],
                      // stops: [0, 1], if you want to adjust the gradiet this is where you would do it
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: This works but its a rectangle that does have a starting gradient/blur

Comment: When I change the blur values, it blurs the whole screen. Why is that?

Comment: sorry I think this will solve the blurring the whole screen issue I added ```ClipRRect``` to above answer

Comment: I edited my question to show you my current code and how it looks. If you could please help

Comment: sorry I didn't mean to have that value at 99 last time i was playing around and never changed it back this should give you a more desirable effect

Comment: So that fixed that. How do i make it fade in from the left? Instead of it just being a block?

Comment: Okay here try this sorry it took so long to get here

Answer (score 7):

You can use `ShaderMask` with a gradient.

You can adjust inside the `LinearGradient` the `stops` and the `colors` to change the effect.

Maybe change `Colors.white` to `Colors.trasnparent`

Please try this code, to see some effect.

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ShaderMask(
          shaderCallback: (Rect bounds) {
            return LinearGradient(
              colors: [Colors.white, Colors.white.withOpacity(0.05)],
              stops: [0.7, 1],
              tileMode: TileMode.mirror,
            ).createShader(bounds);
          },
          child: Container(
            height: 100,
            child: ListView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              children: <Widget>[
                Card(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  child: Center(child: Text("012345678910 - 0123")),
                ),
                Card(
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                  child: Center(child: Text("012345678910 - 0123")),
                ),
                Card(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  child: Center(child: Text("012345678910 - 0123")),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

These are the examples in images:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: @encuboz I want the white part to be grey which I changed but the grey part I don't want  at all (it covers the data). How do I do this?

Comment: Mmmmm, you have to adjust some color parameters to adjust your UI to this. If you can add your listview code and an image, so I can have your "real UI" and work from there.

Comment: See my updated answer, now more independent from the colors of the list items. I change the colors array. Try it.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks

Comment: How do I do this on both right and left sides?

Comment: Anyone found out how to do this for both and only the left side? @LeonardoRignanese