# How do I add a blur effect at the top and bottom edge of vertical scrollView in flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, scrollview, vertical-scrolling, uiblureffect

I'm Trying to implement a vertical Scroll view with multiple items inside. Currently the scroll view works just fine but the edges seems to be very sharp and its cropping like this while scrolling,

[image]

instead I need to blur the top and bottom edge.

I'm looking for something similar to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61151054/12890791, but this answer is for horizontal scroll.

Comment: That is not a blur effect, that is just an elevation which you can provide to any container and it will show shadow like the same.

Comment: please add the code to achieve the same @KaranMehta

Comment: Please share the code of what you've done and I'll add code in that.

Answer (score 0):

Make the appBar transparent, set elevation to zero. In the scaffold, set extendBody and extend bodyBehind appBar to true